# Tensorflow result inconsistent across batch size

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

I was playing around with batch MLP evaluation. Since GPU memory size is limited, I have to use small batches (e.g. 1000x43) of a very large matrix (e.g. 1000000x43). I found the result of the computation inconsistent across batch size. Here is a minimal example:

```
with tf.Session():
    x = tf.Variable(np.random.rand(43, 60000).astype('f2'))
    w = tf.Variable(np.ones((58624, 43), 'f2'))
    b = tf.Variable(np.ones((58624, 1), 'f2'))
    v1 = w @ x + b
    w = tf.Variable(np.ones((5376, 43), 'f2'))
    b = tf.Variable(np.ones((5376, 1), 'f2'))
    v2 = w @ x + b
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    print(v1.eval(), v2.eval())
```

Output:

```
[[ 21.375     18.578125  22.765625 ...,  23.828125  24.203125  22.0625  ]
 [ 21.375     18.578125  22.765625 ...,  23.828125  24.203125  22.0625  ]
 [ 21.375     18.578125  22.765625 ...,  23.828125  24.203125  22.0625  ]
 ..., 
 [ 21.375     18.578125  22.765625 ...,  23.828125  24.203125  22.0625  ]
 [ 21.375     18.578125  22.765625 ...,  23.828125  24.203125  22.0625  ]
 [ 21.375     18.578125  22.765625 ...,  23.828125  24.203125  22.0625  ]] [[ 22.375     19.578125  23.765625 ...,  24.828125  25.203125  23.0625  ]
 [ 22.375     19.578125  23.765625 ...,  24.828125  25.203125  23.0625  ]
 [ 22.375     19.578125  23.765625 ...,  24.828125  25.203125  23.0625  ]
 ..., 
 [ 22.375     19.578125  23.765625 ...,  24.828125  25.203125  23.0625  ]
 [ 22.375     19.578125  23.765625 ...,  24.828125  25.203125  23.0625  ]
 [ 22.375     19.578125  23.765625 ...,  24.828125  25.203125  23.0625  ]]
```

Apparently the result of two batch sizes (58624 and 5376) is off by 1, while it should not happen since the first axis of the matrices `w` and `b` should be broadcast-able.

I'm using `tensorflow-gpu 1.11.0` from `conda`, platform is `Ubuntu Server 18.04.01`, architecture `amd64`, graphics card `Nvidia Titan Xp`. Is there really a bug, or is my logic wrong somewhere?

BTW:

- In this example the result seems to be not related with the value of batch size, but in my actual (much bigger) example, which utilizes regular and batch matrix multiplication (both `@`), broadcast-ed `tanh`, tensor addition (`+`), and `tf.linalg.norm` over last two axis to compute matrix norm in batch, the result seems to be proportional to batch size.
- If I remove the `+b` part from `v1` and `v2`, the result is equivalent. But if I replace the matrix multiplication with a random tensor, I can't reproduce the problem.

The actual bigger example is over here:

```
x = tf.Variable(np.ones((43, 60000), 'f2'))
y = tf.Variable(np.ones((8, 60000), 'f2'))
w = tf.Variable(np.ones((916* 64, 43), 'f2'))
b = tf.Variable(np.ones((916* 64, 1), 'f2'))
v = tf.Variable(np.ones((916, 8, 64), 'f2'))
c = tf.Variable(np.ones((916, 8, 1), 'f2'))
r = tf.linalg.norm(tf.cast(v@tf.reshape(tf.tanh(w@x+b),(916,64,60000))+c,'float32'),axis=(1,2))#prevent overflow
w = tf.Variable(np.ones((84* 64, 43), 'f2'))
b = tf.Variable(np.ones((84* 64, 1), 'f2'))
v = tf.Variable(np.ones((84, 8, 64), 'f2'))
c = tf.Variable(np.ones((84, 8, 1), 'f2'))
R = tf.linalg.norm(tf.cast(v@tf.reshape(tf.tanh(w@x+b),(84,64,60000))+c,'float32'),axis=(1,2))#prevent overflow
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
print(r.eval()[::100], R.eval()[::10])#summary
```

which produces:

```
[ 1906641.625  1906641.625  1906641.625  1906641.625  1906641.625
  1906641.625  1906641.625  1906641.625  1906641.625  1906641.625]
[ 45033.32421875  45033.32421875  45033.32421875  45033.32421875
  45033.32421875  45033.32421875  45033.32421875  45033.32421875
  45033.32421875]
```

Thank you!

Comment: I had similar problems both with and without gpu. With some batch sizes, the value of the loss was getting 2.5 times bigger, so it is not neglectable. Details here (your github issue): https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/23182